# The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32

Tags: apt

I have serious key problems that I am not able to solve.  Apt keeps telling me that I do not have a key that I can verify I DO have.  The normal answer to this issue is 99% of the time to apt-key add the missing key.  However, that is NOT working on this machine and I dont know why.  See below as the commands describe the problem better than I can here.

**EDIT:**  DO NOT SUGGEST apt-key add as a fix.  That is NOT the problem here.  Take note below that the keys are ALREADY listed in apt-key list.  Since the keys exist,  I suspect the problem is in trying to read the key files themselves, (permissions maybe), but IDK where or what to look for to check that

```
Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]                    
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease [242 kB]                            
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]                                   
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]      
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease                   
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
Get:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease [20.8 kB]
Err:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                   
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
Err:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
Get:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic InRelease [20.8 kB]
Err:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
Err:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A1715D88E1DF1F24
Err:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 4F4EA0AAE5267A6C
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A1715D88E1DF1F24
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 4F4EA0AAE5267A6C
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.



root@Work-VirtualBox /etc/apt # apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.23cQALOxzT/gpg.1.sh --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
gpg: key 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32: 21 signatures not checked due to missing keys
gpg: key 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32: "Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2012) <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>" not changed
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:              unchanged: 1


root@Work-VirtualBox /etc/apt # apt-key list
/etc/apt/trusted.gpg
--------------------
pub   rsa4096 2012-05-11 [SC]
      790B C727 7767 219C 42C8  6F93 3B4F E6AC C0B2 1F32
uid           [ unknown] Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2012) <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>

pub   rsa1024 2009-01-22 [SC]
      E1DD 2702 88B4 E603 0699  E45F A171 5D88 E1DF 1F24
uid           [ unknown] Launchpad PPA for Ubuntu Git Maintainers

pub   rsa1024 2009-01-26 [SC]
      14AA 40EC 0831 7567 56D7  F66C 4F4E A0AA E526 7A6C
uid           [ unknown] Launchpad PPA for Ondřej Surý


root@Work-VirtualBox /etc/apt # apt-get update
Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease [88.7 kB]                           
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease [242 kB]            
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease [88.7 kB]                                  
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease [74.6 kB]      
Err:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease                   
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
Get:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease [20.8 kB]
Err:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                   
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
Err:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
Get:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic InRelease [20.8 kB]
Err:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
Err:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A1715D88E1DF1F24
Err:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic InRelease
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 4F4EA0AAE5267A6C
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
E: The repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A1715D88E1DF1F24
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 4F4EA0AAE5267A6C
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This is a question answer site. Please don't put the answer inside the question. Please use the **Answer your own question** button below. After the required time, accept your answer as correct by clicking on the gray check mark ✔️ and turn it green ✅. This will help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out on my own! I was correct in my assumption that it was permissions. I took a shot in the dark and ran:

```
sudo bash
cd /etc/apt
chmod -R 755 .
apt-get update (At this point it began to work!)
exit
```

So if you have tried apt-key add and it doesnt work,  maybe this will work for you.  IDK how these permissions got jacked up, but this seemed to fix whatever it was.

Comment: I have the same problem. This answer didn't work for me.