# Apt Not Recognizing Installed GPG Key

Tags: apt

Seemed like a simple problem, but it wasn't...

I am trying [to install Nodejs on Ubuntu Server 20.04](https://www.vultr.com/docs/installing-node-js-and-express-on-ubuntu-20-04) (ppa) version and I am running into the [GPG error "NO_PUBKEY"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey)

**Things I tried**

I immediately ran `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 1655A0AB68576280`

and it was successful.

```
gpg: key 1655A0AB68576280: public key "NodeSource <gpg@nodesource.com>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
```

However, when I ran `apt-get update`  it still gave me an error

```
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: https://deb.nodesource.com/node_16.x focal InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 1655A0AB68576280
```

Therefore I [verified permissions:](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1372740/the-following-signatures-couldnt-be-verified-because-the-public-key-is-not-avai)

```
cd /etc/apt
chmod -R 755 .
apt-get update
```

And that didn't work.  Any thoughts?

**additional info:**

Just verifying the key is installed... apt just doesn't recognize it

```
#apt-key list
pub   rsa8091 2014-06-13 [SC]
      8FDE3 C675 BC1C 6FC3 1A8A  0A1C 1655 A0AB 6857 6280
uid           [ unknown] NodeSource <gpg@nodesource.com>
sub   rsa8091 2014-06-13 [E]
```

Comment: Try this: `curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/gpgkey/nodesource.gpg.key | gpg --dearmor | sudo apt-key add -`

Comment: @Liso executed without error.. "OK" output, but apt-get still gives the above error when I update

Comment: @Liso  FYI, I also tried using apt-key del to remove the key from the list... succeeded.. and then ran your command to reinstall it... same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When in doubt.. go straight to the source.

It seems the vultr.com's installation instructions were simply out of date.  I went to the nodejs download site for Ubuntu:

https://downloads.nodesource.com/#debian-v16

And I used:

```
#curl -sL https://nsolid-deb.nodesource.com/nsolid_setup_4.x | sudo bash -
#sudo apt-get -y install nsolid-gallium nsolid-console
```

To get the latest version of NodeJS installed. Then verified:

```
node --version  
pm --version
```

On to the next problem... :-)